# Permanently delete Gmail email using Python imaplib

Tags: python, python-2.7, gmail, imap, imaplib

I'm using a Gmail rule to label certain emails as 'delete' to mark for permanently deletion. With this python script I can successfully move them to the Gmail Bin but am unable to permanently delete them once they are there.

Any ideas? I've tried setting auto-expunge in the Gmail imap settings on/off but doesn't change anything.

```
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com', 993)

try:
    rv, data = mail.login(EMAIL_ACCOUNT, EMAIL_PASS)
except imaplib.IMAP4.error as e:
    print "LOGIN FAILED!!! "
    print e
    sys.exit(1)

print rv, data

mail.select("delete")
type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')

mail.store("1:*",'+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')
mail.store("1:*", "+FLAGS", '\\Deleted')
mail.expunge()
```

Comment: You can't really with gmail, without moving them to the Bin/Trash, then *selecting* the bin, finding the message again, and sending the delete flag again.  If you don't move it to the bin first, you just end up removing the folder label and putting it in "All Mail"

Comment: By default on gmail, messages will age out of the trash in 30 days, which might be sufficient for some use cases.

Comment: @Max isn't that what i'm doing with `mail.store("1:*",'+X-GM-LABELS', '\\Trash')
mail.store("1:*", "+FLAGS", '\\Deleted')`, moving it the bin and setting the deleted flag?

Comment: You are setting the deleted flag on the "copy" of it in the current folder, not the Trash copy.  (Gmails emulation of IMAP folders is imperfect and complex.)  You'd need to `select("[Gmail]/Bin")` (watch out for localization), find the message(s), then do the same `mail.store` command but with the UIDs in the trash.   If you're deleting everything, it's straightforward.

Comment: @Max that's great thanks for your help. Wow would have never realised that about the "copy". Yeah gmails imap implementation needs to come with a warning label!

Comment: I will summarize into a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the issues:

Gmail's emulation of IMAP folders means that a message with many labels shows up as a separate copy in many folders.  Some message data and metadata is shared between folders, but other metadata is not.

Placing the `\Deleted` flag on a message removes the current folder/label from the message. If this is the last label, this message becomes archived and is available in the `All Mail` folder.

Using IMAP to move the message to the Trash or Bin folder (via `MOVE` or `COPY`<sup>*1</sup>), or adding the Trash label corresponds to giving it the trash label (and should remove all other labels automatically).  It will then sit there and be purged in 30 days.

To permanently remove a message that you have Trashed, you need to `select` the Bin or Trash folder (its name is locale dependant, you may need `list` to find it), then add the `\Deleted` flag, which corresponds to permanent deletion.

In your example, you've moved the message to the trash, and redundantly removed the current label from the message. You need to switch to the Trash folder to delete it permanently.

*1: If you use `UID MOVE` or `UID COPY`, the `UIDPLUS` response should return the new UID in the Trash folder that you can use to permanently delete an item.

<sub>Note: The IMAP settings UI in Gmail's web interface theoretically has settings to customize this behaviour, but in my experience changing them has no actual effect.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so here a full code that works for me.
Hope it will help somebody.
IMPORTANT: Your emails have to be previously moved to trash!

```
connection = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
connection.login("xxxxx@gmail.com", "xxxxx@gmail.com's account app pwd")
connection.select(mailbox='"[Gmail]/Trash"', readonly=False)
connection.store("1:*", '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
connection.expunge()
connection.close()  # close and logout the connection
connection.logout()
```